# xHow to save UISwitch state whenever the application is quit (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, save, state, uiswitch

How can I save the state of multiple switches so when the application is quit and reopened, all of the switches are not at the same state they where before I quit it.  Here is my very simple code for a quick homework manager I did.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  HomeworkManager
//
//  Created by Nate Parker on 9/2/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Nathan Parker. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func resetClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    spanish.setOn(false, animated: true);
    algebra.setOn(false, animated: true);
    amerCult.setOn(false, animated: true);
    bio.setOn(false, animated: true);
    col.setOn(false, animated: true);
}

@IBOutlet var spanish: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var algebra: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var amerCult: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var bio: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var col: UISwitch


}
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, but you should probably start by reading about [State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html), which is really designed to make it easy to save and restore the state of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `AppDelegate` class, in  `applicationDidEnterBackground` post a notification, so your view controller will be able to be notified when app goes in background:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication!) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kSaveSwitchesStatesNotification", object: nil);   
}
```

In your viewcontroller class add this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.restoreSwitchesStates();

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "saveSwitchesStates", name: "kSaveSwitchesStatesNotification", object: nil);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func saveSwitchesStates() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(spanish!.on, forKey: "spanish");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(algebra!.on, forKey: "algebra");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(amerCult!.on, forKey: "amerCult");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(bio!.on, forKey: "bio");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(col!.on, forKey: "col");

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
}

func restoreSwitchesStates() {
    spanish!.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("spanish");
    algebra!.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("algebra");
    amerCult!.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("amerCult");
    bio!.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("bio");
    col!.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("col");
}
```

First thing add viewcontroller as an observer for the notification posted when app goes in background. When this notification will be triggered it will call `saveSwitchesStates()` method which will save switches states in `NSUserDefaults`. Also in `viewDidLoad()` call `restoreSwitchesStates()` which will read stored bools for switches states from `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to save there state when application is going to close and load them back when the app launches.
Tutorial explaining how to save data using `NSUserDefaults`

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: Not my down vote however that link is for objective C, the OP is using Swift